# Code first (re)mapping pure array to ICollection

Tags: .net, web-services, ef-code-first

I’m trying to map a webservice response class (generated in service reference) to a SQL DB using code-first approach but I have faced the following issue:

Some of the data in the targeted class is stored in pure array as shown below in sample:

```
public partial class Message
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Tag[] Tags { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tag
{
    public string ShortTag { get; set; }
    public string FullTag { get; set; }        
}
```

To fit the code first requirements those sample classes are extended as shown:

```
public partial class Message
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ICollection<Tag> CTags
    {
        get { return Tags == null ? new Collection<Tag>() : Tags.ToList(); }
        set { Tags = value.ToArray(); }
    }
}

public partial class Tag
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext looks like:

```
public class SampleContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasMany(x => x.Tags);
    }
}
```

Database is successfully generated and looks as expected.
Setting and saving messages and tags is also working but **retrieving always gives empty array.**

Changing the above code to:

```
public partial class Message
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ICollection<Tag> CTags { get; set; }        
}
```

fixes the issue, but I need the mapping to the pure array as it is used by the webservice in the XML serialization for the SOAP.

Please advise how to proceed or what I'm doing wrong?